# Screen flickering when I run commands in gnome-terminal

Tags: screen, flicker

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.10.

I frequently see screen flickering, but only when I open the terminal and run some commands, not when I use browsers or at any other time. When I press keyboard keys to type commands in the terminal I see flickers and after some time my entire screen goes blank, (but my laptop does not switch off) and I then have to force shut down every time. This problem does not happen when i am working on windows.

My graphics driver is Intel corporation core processor integrated graphics controller

Answer (score 3):

I oserved the same thing using Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.04. Changing the desktop environment did not help. I tested Gnome3, gnome-flashback, mate...

I am able to reproduce the issue with gnome-terminal, xterm, and also gedit.
I am not able to reproduce it with libre-office writer, firefox (google search input line).

The problem occours much more often when key presses are combined with simultaniously moving the mouse cursor.

I fixed the problem by changing accelerate mode from SNA back to UXA:

Create a file /etc/X11/xorg.conf with the following content:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option     "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Nowadays the recommended location for xorg configs is a file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, which is - when done right - less prone to unintended side-effects.